# pegar cliente com determinados tipos de compras

Tags: c#, linq, expressões-lambda

Tenho essas tabelas:

> Vendas : IDVenda(int)PK, DataVenda(DateTime), QdeItem(Decimal),
>   ValorVenda(Decimal).IDItem(FK),IDCliente(FK)
>
> Item: IDItem(int)PK,Descricao(Varchar),ValorItem(Decimal)
>
> Cliente:IDCliente(int)PK,Nome(varchar),DataCadastro(DateTime)

Como eu faço para filtrar somente os cliente que compraram 5 ou mais bicicletas e um pneu pelo menos, usando `LINQ` apenas?

Comment: Na aplicação, cliente possui uma lista de Vendas?

Comment: Voce utiliza EntityFramework?

Comment: Isso deverá ser feito com LINQ ou Sql normal. Só peciso dentre uma lista de coisas vendidas, a linq ou sql deveria retornar quem comprou acima de cinco carros e um pneu.

Answer (score 1):

você pode realizar a seguinte consulta:

```
public IEnumerable<int> getClientes(int itemID, int qtdMinimo)
{
    return (
        from venda in db.Vendas
        where venda.IDItem == itemID
        group venda by venda.IDCliente into grupo
        where grupo.Sum(venda => venda.QdeItem) >= qtdMinimo
        select grp.Key
    );
}
```

No caso acima, será retornado todos os clientes que compraram mais de 5 itens do produto informado, independente destes produtos terem sido comprados no mesmo pedido.

**P.S: Não foi testado**